# Restore NTFS partition from linux

Tags: linux, windows, data-recovery

One of my unscrupulous users decided to format his Windows XP NFTS hard-disk before he left the company.

Are there any Linux based tools that would allow me to rebuild the partition?

Comment: The user reformatted a ext2/3 disk to NTFS before separation?

Comment: Oh wait.  your answer comment indicates that an NTFS disk was reformated.  Is that it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When searching for information this area of recovery is often referred to as forensics.  You are going to have a tough time if the person did any sort of non-quick format.  For Linux you can try [testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) which is in Ubuntu's repositories.  Be sure to mount the disk as read only. And you might have an easier time if you use dd to create an image. [This](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/10385) Linux Journal article talks about disk forensics a bit (not sure if you subscription to view it or not).

Comment: This worked perfectly. Completely restoring the disk and allowing Windows to boot normally.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest trying out some of the partition tools on the [Ultimate Boot Cd](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/)